# Is object-oriented PHP slow?

Tags: php, oop, performance

I used to use procedural-style PHP. Later, I used to create some classes. Later, I learned Zend Framework and started to program in OOP style. Now my programs are based on my own framework (with elements of cms, but without any design *in* framework), which is built on the top of the Zend Framework.

Now it consists of lots classes. But the more I program, more I'm afraid. I'm afraid that my program will be slow because of them I'm afraid to add every another one class which can help me to develop but can slow the application.

All I know is that including lots of files slows application (using eAccelerator + gathering all the code in one file can speed up application 20 times!), but I have no idea if creating new classes and objects slows PHP by itself.

Does anyone have any information about it?

Comment: If your program is getting slow you may reconsider your class structure and how do you implement your objects. I never have heard that OOP is slower than procedural-style.

Comment: Thanks for your edits, Thomas! One thing: I think, the new title makes a bit different sense. Though, my English isn't well and I won't rollback, just comment :)

Comment: @backslash17 I don't think my program is slow. But I'm afraid if another 10 classes will make it slow. Another 50? Another 100?

Comment: That's why you  have inheritance! Why 50 classes or 100? Just inherit common behaviors. That`s why i`m talking about to reconsider class structure if you need to create 50 or 100 classes more.

Comment: Of course I inherit them! For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641940/emulate-multiple-inheritance-in-php

Comment: @backslash: you really never heard that OOP is slower than procedural style? http://tinyurl.com/ygyclo9 ;)
It depends, in human-time, when this is negligible or not ;)

Comment: OOP is harder to maintain and slower to develop. It also uses many times the memory for the same task and also makes everything slower. I'm still wondering what OOP has to offer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's [good article discussing the issue.](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2005/01/11/oop-and-performance/) I also have seen some [anecdotal bench-marks](http://www.theserverpages.com/articles/webmasters/php/performance/Performance_of_OOP_PHP_versus_non-OOP.html) that will put OOP PHP overhead at 10-15%
Personally I think OOP is better choice since at the end it may perform better just because it probably was better designed and thought through. Procedural code tends to be messy and hard to maintain. So at the end - it has to be how critical is performance difference for your app vs. ability to maintain, extend and simply comprehend

Comment: thanks! (btw, does the Script B in anecdotal bench-marking work? I think, where $basket should be passed by reference. Or I'm too C-lish?:)

Comment: Imho, never choose one or the another with blinded eyes.
If the script is small, and you need full performance, go with procedural, trying to write the less spaghetti that you can.
If the script (not the project, i mean the script.. big projects have many small scripts, some in oop, some in procedural) and you need full maintainability, go with oop.

Comment: I agree and I'm (sorta) making the same point at the very end

Comment: OOP makes more difficult to think when you're trying to solve a problem so a program made in OOP designed worse and performs really bad. OOP tends to be messy and harder to maintain but also largely increases the amount of code for a given program.

Comment: So in the end, what are you answering things you have no experience about? Stop lying to people.

Comment: It's been more than 10 years, but just so it's registered here: All variables in PHP afaik are copy-on-write, especially the ones representing objects. So there are fewer reasons to use references in PHP, like output arguments or inplace modifications w/ foreach loops, and since it's a bit of a footgun I'd say avoid it unless your benchmarks are really showing at lot of improvment to justify the risks.

Answer (score 41):

This bugs me. See...procedural code is not always spaghetti code, yet the OOP fanboys always presume that it is. I've written several procedural based web apps as well as an IRC services daemon in PHP. Amazingly, it seems to outperform most of the other ones that are out there and editing it is super easy. One of my friends who generally does OOP took a look at it and said "no code has the right to be this clean"

Conversely, I wrote my own PHP framework (out of boredom) and it was done in a purely OOP manner.

A good programmer can write great procedural code without the overhead classes bring. A bad programmer who uses OOP will always write crappy OOP code that slows things down.

There is no one right answer to which is better for PHP, but rather which is better for the exact scenario.

Comment: So true. The decency of the code totally depends on the person who wrote it rather than the fact that it is OO or Functional.

Comment: @Jeremy I'd like to see a link to this marvelously clean procedural code you mention.  i.e., "pics or it didn't happen."  :)

Comment: Interesting notion here. Can you confirm what sort of *size* application you are writing? A 5 or even 20 file app even with some DB access (etc) can easily be written *cleanly* in procedural. However, when you have a larger scale with all kinds of components, I'm not convinced it would *glue together* as well as it would using mostly, at least *some*, objects to pass around.

Comment: PHP by design is not as OOP oriented language like Java for example. As such OOP design needs to be blended with procedural in a ratio completely dependant on the individual project in a way that will benefit from the best possible maintainability that does not compromise performance. Going all OOP crazy on it will yield performance issues that will stray OOP fans away and inspire hatred for the language while doing things procedural might yield performant code it will also cause serious issues in maintaining and extending the functionalities. Think for yourselves, the book is just a guide.

Comment: "A bad programmer will always write crappy OOP code that slows things down"

BS. A bad programmer i no more likely to write OOP than not...

Comment: At last a proper answer. no OOP unsustainable BS. I can't believe how they think OOP is more maintainable or less spaghetti when OOP is the worst choice ever for those two points. My code is also as clean as you mentioned and things are not only more maintainable but everything weights so little that it gets to reduce memory usage up to a 1%. OOP is really the worst thing that could ever happen to programmers.

Comment: I get to develop dozens of features a week sometimes many a day and yet OOP coders can barely fix a bug in a week and for some reason OOP is helping them on maintainability.

Comment: @James I make 3D engines and animation tools which are huge and have to deal with everything you can think of. I used OOP before but since I don't anymore the code is being reduced up to a 10% or less so yeah it's more maintainable without OOP, particularly for a large system where multiplication of your code size is a really bad thing.

Answer (score 12):

The most important thing to remember is, design first, optimize later. A better design, which is more maintainable, is better than spaghetti code. Otherwise, you might as well write your web app in assembler. After you're done, you can profile (instead of guess), and optimize what seems slowest.

Comment: profiling php is such a headache (for reading XDebug's files I have to use Linux. Or use the strange Air application which isn't show any info, but only convert the file into the other odd format. Or I can use Zend Debugger, but I don't really want to buy Zend Studio now)

Comment: Wincachegrind has been fine for reading profiler output under windows for me.

Comment: There is also webcachegrind, which is pretty interface to xdebug profile logs.

Comment: Use Xdebug grinder to identify what to optimise. Also use Intellij to step thru the code and see what's going on, that can be so so helpful. For those that find these tools complicated just use php's built in *tick* or use the autoloader or add some markers to time things or all. There are tons of benchmarking tools. You have no excuse. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.declare.php#control-structures.declare.ticks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, every include makes your program slower, but there is more to it than that.

If you decompose your program, over many files, there is a point where you're including/parsing/executing the least amount of code, vs the overhead of including all those files.

Furthermore, having lots of files with little code ain't so bad, because, as you said, using things like eAccelerator, or APC, is a trivial way to get a crap ton of performance back. At the same time you get, if you believe in them, all the wonderful benefits of having and Object Oriented code base.

Also, slow on a per request basis != not scalable.

**Updated**

As requested, PHP is still faster at straight up array manipulation than it is classes. I vaguely remember the doctrine ORM project, and someone comparing hydration of arrays versus objects, and the arrays came out faster. It's not an order of magnitude, it is noticable, however -- [this is in french, but the code and results are completely understandable.](http://www.amicalement-web.net/benchmark-apache-doctrine-hydrate-object-vs-array/2009/10/08/). Just a note, that doctrine uses magic methods __get, and __set a lot, and these are also slower than an explicit variable access, part of doctrine's object hydration slowness could be attributed to that, so I would treat it as a worst case scenario. Lastly, even if you're using arrays, if you have to do a lot of moving around in memory, or tonnes of tests, such as isset, or functions like 'in_array' (it's order N), you'll screw the performance benefits. Also remember that objects are just arrays underneath, the interpreter just treats them as a special. I would, personally, favour better code than a small performance increase, you'll get more benefit from having smarter algorithms.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the last line! It kills lots of my doubts :) What about the other lines, as I said, I know about include and asking about classes themself :)

Answer (score 2):

If your project contains many files and due to the nature of PHP's file access checking and restrictions, I'd recommend to turn on `realpath_cache`, bump up the configuration settings to reasonable numbers, and turn off `open_basedir` and `safe_mode`. Ensure to use PHP-FPM or SuExec to run the php process under a user id which is restricted to the document root to get back the security one usually gains from `open_basedir` and/or `safe_mode`.

Here are a few pointers why this is a performance gain:

- https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=46965
- http://nirlevy.blogspot.de/2009/01/slow-lstat-slow-php-slow-drupal.html

Also consider my comment on the answer from @Ólafur:

> I found especially auto-loading to be the biggest slow down. PHP is extremely slow for directory lookup and file open access, the more PHP function you use during a custom auto-loader, the bigger the slow-down. You can help it a bit with turning off safe-mode (deprecated anyways) or even open-basedir (but I would not do that), but the biggest improvement comes from not using auto-loading and simply use "require_once" with complete fs pathes to require all dependencies per php file you use.

Comment: +1 for the information, though not an answer to the main question ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using large frameworks for web apps that actually do not require so large number of classes for everything is probably the worst problem that many are not aware of. Strip it down at least not to include every bit of code, keep just what you need and throw the rest.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using include_once() then you are causing an unnecessary slowdown, regardless of OOP design or not.

OOP will add an overhead to your code but I will bet that you will never notice it.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I think I should remember it. Btw, I don't use includes very often. I prefer autoloading files then testing and gathering the bigger part of them in the one file then uploading to production

Comment: I found especially auto-loading to be the biggest slow down. PHP is extremely slow for directory lookup and file open access, the more PHP function you use during a custom auto-loader, the bigger the slow-down. You can help it a bit with turning off safe-mode (deprecated anyways) or even open-basedir (but I would not do that), but the biggest improvement comes from not using auto-loading and simply use "require_once" with complete fs pathes to require all dependencies per php file you use.

Answer (score 0):

You may reconsider to rethink your classes structure and how do you implement them. If you said that OOP is slower you may have to redesign your classes and how do you implement them. A class is just a template of an object, any bad designed method affects all the objects of that class.

Use inheritance and polimorfism the most you can, this will effectively reduce the amount of behaviors and independent methods your classes need, but first off all you need to create a good inheritance map, abstracting your first or mother classes as much as you can.

It is not a problem about how many classes do you have, the problem is how many methods, properties or fields they have and how well are those methods structured. Inheritance reduces the amount of methods to design drammatically and the amount of code to be compiled too.

Comment: I haven't said that 'OOP is slower'. I've asked, if it is.

Answer (score 0):

As several other people have pointed out, there is a mild overhead to OO PHP, but you can offset it by focusing your optimization effort on the core classes that your various other classes derive from.  This is why C++ is becoming increasingly popular in the world of high-performance computing, traditionally the realm of C and Fortran.

Personally, I've never seen a PHP server that was CPU-constrained.  Check your RAM use (you can optimize the core classes for this as well) and make sure you're not making unnecessary database calls, which are orders of magnitude more expensive than any extra CPU work you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you design a huge OOP object hog, that does everything rather than doing functional decomposition to various classes, you will obviously fill up the memory with useless ballast code. Also, with a slow framework you will not make a simply hello World any fast. I noticed it is a kind trend (bad habit) that for one single facebook icon, people include a hole awesome font library and then next there is a search icon with fontello included. Each time they accomplish something unusual, they connect an entire framework. If you want to create a fast loading oop app use one framework only like zephir-phalcon or whatever you fancy and stick to it.

Answer (score -1):

There are ways to limit the penalty from the include_once entries, and that's by having functions declared in the 'include_once' file that themselves have their code content in an 'include' statement.  This will load your library of code, but only those functions actually being used will load code as it is needed.  You take a second file system hit for the included code, but memory usages drop to practically nothing for the library itself, and only the code used by your program gets loaded.  The hit from the second file system access can be mitigated by caching. When dealing with a large project of procedural based PHP, this provides low memory usage and fast processing.  DO NOT do this with classes.  This would be for a production instance, a development server will show all the penalty of hits since you don't want caching turned on.