# Including layout files - Best approach

Tags: php, layout, include

When developping applications I include phtml files to build the interface and keep the logic away from the design.

I have made some tests with 3 different approaches to include those files and came to this result:

1. include(FORMS_FOLDER."/campaign/create.phtml") - Load time: 0,00011491775512695
2. $render->form(**FILE**) - Load time: 0,00013995170593262 -> 21.78% increase
3. Render::form(**FILE**) -> Load time: 0,00019311904907227 -> 68.04% increase

Even though the load time is very fast which option should I stick to?

Comment: With three zeros after the comma, i think you're good.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the first method is fastest because it's a native function in PHP. With options two and three, the OOP style is causing PHP to think for a split second and translate the $render->form() method into an include statement.

I'd go with option 2 or 3 if you're trying to keep an expressive, OOP style approach.

Answer (score 0):

Second option. Check a bit how some "more important" frameworks do it since their approaches are carefully  picked.

For example,check how Symfony2 implemented it. Pay attention to `render` function, here is start location from which you can trace the rest

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php

Since in just 2 weeks using it I became absolute **Symfony2 fan** , you could check out their Form component. You can use it by itself without using whole full-stack framework.

Update:
You could also check out http://twig.sensiolabs.org/ which is a template engine if importing third-party code is an option for you :)

Update 2: Native PHP methods are the fastest, but not always the best way to go. If you are building anything more then 1-file 1-purpose script, I would suggest OOP approach, thats why I vote for option #2. Note that OOP apps are **slower** then procedural ones but they allow much *better* structuring and easier mainenance. As for speed difference, you could check out: [Is object-oriented PHP slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651759/is-object-oriented-php-slow)